# How to add indicator to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

[image: stumbleupon app - android]

How to add those small circles depicting number of pages user can flip through? I have tried using Jake Wharton's library but its giving me problems like

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-03-29 18:10:56 - WhatsMyPassword] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the   dependency list,
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to do it or how to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewPagerIndicator` library uses an other version of `android-support-v4.jar` than you do. If you replace the `.jar` file in the library with your local copy, it should work.

Comment: yes. It worked. Thank you. I just replaced the jar file in the library with latest version.